# Configuring ucanaccess driver on wildfly 8.0

Tags: driver, datasource, wildfly

I am trying to create a web application using MS Access as database. For it, I am using ucanaccess driver and my server is Wildfly 8.0

The issue is to how correctly configure this driver on the server ?
After researching on internet I got to know below steps

1. create a folder structre and place all the ucanaccess jar files-

   `wildfly-8.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\ucanaccess\jdbc\main`
2. Edit module.xml file-

```xml
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.ucanaccess.jdbc">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ucanaccess-2.0.9.4.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-lang-2.6.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hsqldb.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackcess-2.0.8.jar"/>            
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

3. Edit standalone-full.xml file

```xml
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>

    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/MyDS" pool-name="MyDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:ucanaccess://C://Users//sahashu//Documents//NGCORE.accdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
        <driver>ucanaccess-2.0.9.4.jar</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name></user-name>
            <password></password>
        </security>
    </datasource>

    <drivers>
        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>

        <driver name="ucanaccess" module="com.ucanaccess.jdbc">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.ucanaccess.jdbc.MsAccessDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>

    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

However, still I get this error-

```
23:29:34,422 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "datasources"),
("jdbc-driver" => "ucanaccess")
]) - failure description: "JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [com.ucanaccess.jdbc]"
```

Please help me to identify the issue

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why it can't see the module unless it doesn't exist. A minor note though the `<driver/>` on your `java:jboss/MyDS` should be `ucanaccess` not `ucanaccess-2.0.9.4.jar`.

Comment: Thanks James

When you say module doesn't exist, what I need to check exactly ?

Comment: org.ucanaccess.jdbc.MsAccessDataSource doesn't exist, and UCanAccess doesn't provide an XaDatasource but a NonXA. Use other configuration options.

Comment: Try modifying the `<driver>ucanaccess-2.0.9.4.jar</driver>` `<driver>com.ucanaccess.jdbc</driver>` in the datasource configuration.

Comment: @Ashu did you figure this out? I am trying to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way: Just create your own JAR using the UcanAccess JAR files.
In Eclipse:

- Create a plain Java Project (for Java 8)
- Create a dummy class with a dummy main method, and execute it (for example a simple Hello World program)
- Right-click on the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
- Go to the Libraries tab and use "Add External JARs" to add all 5 JARs that you find in your UcanAccess download
- Right-click on the project -> Export -> Java / Runnable JAR file, choose your dummy class as Launch configuration, and keep Library handling as "Extract required libraries..."

Now go to your WildFly administration console, and click on "Deployments". There you can add your freshly baked JAR and enable it. WildFly will recognize this driver automatically from now on, when you need to add a Microsoft Access Datasource using the Wizard in the administration console.